# How to access a (redis) server hosted on a VMWare virtual box?

Tags: networking, debian, python, vmware

I'm pretty new on VMWare and on the "developing world".

**I wanted to start a server (redis) on a VMWare debianOS to be accessed from my main OS** (windows 10), by another (python django) server, to manage channels and etc...

The server is created on my debian desktop

```
root@debian:/home/guido# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But I can't connect to it from my django server and don't know how to do it right.

**What I tried:**

- Scan my main (windows) network with* `cmd:netstat -b` and I can't find the redis server specified.
- Start the server on different connections in [VM Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpMas.png) and scan with `netstat`.
- Start a python (and some others) server in Debian (using bridged and NAT VMware network settings) and I can listen them with `cmd:netstat -b`, but I can't connect to them, maybe I'm doing something wrong.*

I would appreciate if you help me not only to achieve the redis connection, and also what network setting should be the best for what I'm doing, what errors I have, and so on.

_____UPDATE

When i use [NAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J93h.png) Connection and i can't see the server on host

When i use [BRIDGED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdHhK.png) No connection and i can't see the server on host

Comment: Set your guest machines to bridged networking for simplicity. Default is NAT.

Comment: When i use NAT, i got internet connection and can't access to redis from my host.
When i use bridged, there is no internet connection and can't access to it.

Does you know a way to access to the redis server easily from my host? or at least, check if it can be accessed.

Comment: No internet with Bridged networking is very strange. The guest should get an IP from the router.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: What does PING say? Just nothing?

Comment: Nothing.
It looks like my wi-fi or net adapter is not recognizing vmware.
I can add that my vmware MAC doesn't appears in cmd:arp -a

Comment: Reinstall both wireless and wired network drivers for the host machine and restart everything